# msbuild deployment - Only delete folders in package

Tags: deployment, msbuild, msdeploy

I am using msbuild to build and deploy a package for a web application. I have a question on how files are synced. Let's say I have the following folder structure:

```
-Root
    -Pages*
    -Javascript*
    -CMS
```

Folders with asterisks(*) are in my visual studio project, folders without are not but they exist within the application.

Now if I deploy this using msbuild ... /t:Package /p:DeployOnBuild=True .. all folders/files would be deleted pre-publish. This is bad because I need to keep the "CMS" folder.

If I deploy adding "/p:SkipExtraFilesOnServer=True" the CMS folder will not be deleted, but the "Pages" and "Javascript" are not deleted/synced/cleaned either.

**How can I make sure that none-project folder are not touched but that project-folders are synced with the package?**

Answer (score 0):

You can skip specific directories that you don't want deleted by adding the following to your `pubxml` (or `ProjectName.wpp.targets` if you are still using the VS2010 RTM stuff)

```
<MsDeploySkipRules>
  <SkipAction></SkipAction>
  <ObjectName>dirPath</ObjectName>
  <AbsolutePath>CMS</AbsolutePath>
</MsDeploySkipRules>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and I should have mentioned this in my question but I'd prefer not to use this kind of black listing. New files and folder may at some time be added to the application.